# How to match data from two tables with same primary key in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two tables with data about people:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(113,202,377,288,359),
                  name=c("Alex","Silvia","Peter","Jack","Jonny"))
```

Which provides me with

```
   id   name
1 113   Alex
2 202 Silvia
3 377  Peter
4 288   Jack
5 359  Jonny
```

And I have a second table containing the names of their family members:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(113,113,113,202,202,359,359,359,359),
                 family.members=c("Ross","Jefferson","Max","Jo","Michael","Jimmy","Rex","Bill","Larry"))
```

This provides me with:

```
> df2
   id family.members
1 113           Ross
2 113      Jefferson
3 113            Max
4 202             Jo
5 202        Michael
6 359          Jimmy
7 359            Rex
8 359           Bill
9 359          Larry
```

Now I want to extend table 1 with an additional column containing the sum of family members for each person:

```
    id   name no.family.memebers
1  113   Alex                  3
2  202 Silvia                  2
3  377  Peter                  0
4  288   Jack                  0
5  359  Jonny                  4
```

What is the best way to create the third table in R?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Look at `data.table` package. Join table and count/group by is something you need to look for :)

Comment: Added some becnhmarks to my answer to those whose interested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% left_join((
    df2 %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(no.family.members = n())
    )
)
```

---

With `dplyr` >= 0.3.0.2 it could be rewritten as

```
df3 <- df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% count(id))
```

Comment: With the latest dplyr version, you might be able to simplify this to `df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% count(id))` (+1)

Comment: @beginneR I feel that deserves an answer rather than a comment.  I almost missed it except you point to it in another comment.

Comment: @TylerRinker, I have added it to Gregor's answer, hoping that he won't mind :) (otherwise, just delete roll it back, Gregor)

Answer (score 5):

```
 df1 <- df1[order(df1$id), ]  # Just to be safe
 # the counts vector will be ordered by df2$id
 counts <- with (df2, tapply(family.members, id, length))
 df1$no.family.members[df1$id %in% names(counts)]<- counts
 df1
   id   name no.family.members
1 113   Alex                 3
2 202 Silvia                 2
4 288   Jack                NA
5 359  Jonny                 4
3 377  Peter                NA
```

(I think NA is a more informative result than 0.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this instead of `dplyr` (to convert a `data.frame` to a `data.table` you just do `data.table(my_data_frame)`:

```
require(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1, key="id")
df2 <- data.table(df2, key="id")
rslt = df2[df1,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,list(name = unique(name), no.family.members=length(na.omit(family.members))),by=id]
#rslt
#    id   name no.family.members
#1: 113   Alex                 3
#2: 202 Silvia                 2
#3: 288   Jack                 0
#4: 359  Jonny                 4
#5: 377  Peter                 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `data.table` version

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2), id)[, list(no.family.memebers = .N), by = id][df1]
#    id no.family.memebers   name
# 1: 113                  3   Alex
# 2: 202                  2 Silvia
# 3: 288                 NA   Jack
# 4: 359                  4  Jonny
# 5: 377                 NA  Peter
```

Or for v 1.9.4+, using `.EACHI` (contributed by @Arun)

```
setkey(setDT(df2), id)[df1, list(no.family.memebers = .N, name), by=.EACHI]
#     id no.family.memebers   name
# 1: 113                  3   Alex
# 2: 202                  2 Silvia
# 3: 377                  0  Peter
# 4: 288                  0   Jack
# 5: 359                  4  Jonny
```

---

Adding some benchmarks on a bit bigger data sets (both `data.table` solutions posted in this answer win by far, while `.EACHI` implementation is the most efficient one)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

df1 <- data.frame(id=c(seq_len(26)),
                  name = LETTERS)
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e6
df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(seq_len(26), n, replace = TRUE),
                  family.members = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE))

df1.1 <- copy(df1)
df2.2 <- copy(df2)

Gregordplyr <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1 %>% left_join(
  df2 %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(no.family.members = n()))
}

begineRdplyr <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% count(id))
}

BDbaseR <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1 <- df1[order(df1$id), ] 
  counts <- with (df2, tapply(family.members, id, length))
  df1$no.family.members[df1$id %in% names(counts)]<- counts
  df1
}

AlexDT <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1 <- data.table(df1, key="id")
  df2 <- data.table(df2, key="id")
  df2[df1,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,
          list(name = unique(name), 
          no.family.members=length(na.omit(family.members))),
          by=id]
}

DavdDT <- function(df1, df2) {
  setkey(setDT(df2), id)[, list(no.family.memebers = .N), by = id][df1]
}

DavdDTV2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  setkey(setDT(df2), id)[, list(no.family.memebers = .N), by = id][setkey(setDT(df1), id)]
}

ArunDT <- function(df1, df2) {
  setkey(setDT(df2), id)[df1, list(no.family.memebers = .N, name), by=.EACHI]
}

ArunDTV2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  setkey(setDT(df2), id)[setkey(setDT(df1), id), list(no.family.memebers = .N, name), by=.EACHI]
}


Res <- microbenchmark(Gregordplyr(df1, df2),
               begineRdplyr(df1, df2),
               BDbaseR(df1, df2),
               AlexDT(df1.1, df2.2),
               ArunDT(df1.1, df2.2),
               ArunDTV2(df1.1, df2.2),
               DavdDT(df1.1, df2.2),
               DavdDTV2(df1.1, df2.2)
)

Res
# Unit: milliseconds
#                   expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  Gregordplyr(df1, df2) 43.567614 46.486239  51.154432  47.943481  50.711707  93.40908   100
# begineRdplyr(df1, df2) 43.817494 46.105103  51.298581  47.878149  50.613609 125.07362   100
#      BDbaseR(df1, df2) 88.098035 97.065111 121.290967 129.912539 137.914435 179.60281   100
#   AlexDT(df1.1, df2.2) 55.004083 63.029861  88.840319  99.043231 104.272165 284.40967   100
#   ArunDT(df1.1, df2.2)  4.608774  4.967607   6.621559   5.412694   6.584724  45.88562   100
# ArunDTV2(df1.1, df2.2)  4.870497  5.305124   6.381737   5.593097   6.429782  34.93075   100
#   DavdDT(df1.1, df2.2)  8.578043  9.074449  11.943810   9.585854  10.693341  55.91518   100
# DavdDTV2(df1.1, df2.2)  8.822792  9.508088  11.467790   9.970544  11.009343  51.58866   100

boxplot(Res)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks much more compact than the other data.table answer (+1), but still a little lengthy compared to `df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% count(id))` ;)

Comment: @beginneR, my guess is that Arun can come up with something smarter and I'm just lacking expertise here :)

Comment: This is what I always find noticeable about data.table: there are  many different ways to do things and usually only Arun knows the best way (or is the one who suggests some edit that reduce the code to half). Just to be clear: my comment was just meant to tease you a little bit (since normally data.table is more compact in code)

Comment: Seems this will do the same `setDT(df1); setDT(df2); setkey(df2[, list(no.family.members=.N), by=id], id)[df1]`

Comment: `setkey(setDT(df2), id)[df1, .N, by=.EACHI]`.

Comment: So here is the final data.table answer! Thanks, @Arun :)

Comment: @beginneR, now that I think of it, I could simplify my answer too, which makes it even more compact than Aruns, see my edit

Comment: @beginneR, brilliant idea with the `left_join` in `dplyr` but I'm wondering how it performance efficiency wise. Maybe put some benchmarks soon

Comment: I'm sure if you make the data large enough, data.table will outperform dplyr (this wouldn't be surprising). Let's see the numbers

Comment: Looks like a significant difference, even a bit more than I'd expected.